# Is it possible to have alternating conditions in a method in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, subclass, superclass

So I want to create an array of polymorphic classes in Java. It's an array of animals and I want to add different kinds of animals to the array. Animal is the super class and the different kinds of animals are sub classes and I need to implement a method that adds a specific animal to the array based on the attributes but since all kinds of animals have different attributes, I don't know how to do that.
I have this basic method so far and it compiles:

```
public void addAnimal(String name, double weight) {
        if ((numberanimals < animals.length) && (numberanimals == 0)) {
            animals[0] = new Animal(name, weight);
            numberanimals += 1;
        } else if (numberanimals < animals.length) {
            animals[numberanimals] = new Animal(name, weight);
            numberanimals += 1;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Zoo is full.");
            }
}
```

All animals have a name and a weight but how do I add a dog for instance based on his leash length or a shark with a boolean value that says whether he's hungry or not. Is it even possible to do that in one method like that?

Comment: Normally you would create the animal first and pass it to `addAnimal(Animal a)` (like `addAnimal(new Giraffe("Shorty"))`).

Comment: You should change the method to `public void addAnimal(Animal animal)` and it will be able to receive any type of animal (classes that inherit from Animal). Then you just create the animal before calling the method.

Comment: You could an abstract predicate method to the superclass and override it with different selection conditions in the subclasses.

Comment: Addanimal can then use the overridden method to decide whether or not to add an instance of a subclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Each `Crocodile` is an `Animal`.
2. `Animal` has guaranteed access to `Animal` methods and public fields.
3. You can check if an `Animal` is a `Crocodile` using `animal instanceOf Crocodile`
4. If it is a Crocodile, you can cast: `Crocodile croco = (Crocodile)animal;`.
5. You can add `Crocodile` to `Animal[]` or to `List<Animal>` as it is an `Animal`.
6. Every object is an `instanceOf Object`, as all classes extend `Object`.

Your method should be:

```
public void addAnimal(Animal a){
    if ((numberanimals < animals.length) && (numberanimals == 0)) {
        animals[0] = a;
        numberanimals += 1;
    } else if (numberanimals < animals.length) {
        animals[numberanimals] = a;
        numberanimals += 1;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Zoo is full.");
        }
    }
}
```

and then you can call it with any `Animal` - a `Lion` - `addAnimal(new Lion(...));` etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the exact class of an instance by calling 'instanceof'.
For example :

```
if(animals[i] instanceof Dog) {
 //do something
}
```

Comment: That helped me with another task but how can I use an attribute of the dog then. `animals[i].leash` for instance doesn't work.

Comment: you have to cast it to dog first, since the Animal class doesn't have a leash property. `((Dog)animals[i]).leash` you have to make sure it is a Dog class instance !!